# Why we dont use code behind concept in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-behind

I was just going through this asp.net MVC pattern and someone suggested not to use code behind.
Is there any specific reason for that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the whole pattern is based on not using a codebehind file.  any code that is not related to display should be in the controller or a supporting class.